# -Djavax.net.debug=ssl windows no output

Tags: java, windows, debugging, ssl, rcp

i'm trying to debug an ssl issue with a java app on a windows client. Adding

-Djavax.net.debug=ssl

to the applications ini-file does not produce any output. Running that config on a linux machine (ubuntu) i get the debug log i want to, but starting the app from the windows commandline does not produce anything. seems like i'm doing something wrong here or the app is not able to write to standard out on windows (7/64) or writes somewhere else i do not know of.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: still not able to produce any log-output, "-Djavax.net.debug=all" behaves the same way on windows 7/64

Answer (score 0):

since we are using osgi, i had to add "-console" to my binary call. The stdout seems to write to the osgi-console in this case. Problem solved.

Comment: piping the output from windows console via
binary.exe > log.txt 2>&1
catches all the needed information and writes it to log.txt, thats what i needed in first place